# Linear algebra math question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a = \left<2,1\right>$ and $b = \left<1,-5\right>$. Show that there are scalars $s$ and $t$ so that $sa + tb = \left<-1,-28\right>$

So far, I did this and don't know what to do at this point because I am not sure if s or t will be decimal numbers.

$$s(2,1) + t(1,-5)$$

1. $2s + 1t = -1$
2. $1s -5 t = -28$

Comment: Do you know how to solve a system of two equations in two variables?

Comment: Try solving for one variable in one equation and then plugging it into the other.

Answer (score 2):

+1) Since you tagged it as a linear algebra question, here is a linear algebra approach: Your system of equations can written as a matrix equation:$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\1&-5 \end{bmatrix} $
$\begin{bmatrix} s\\t \end{bmatrix} $=$\begin{bmatrix} -1\\-28 \end{bmatrix} $
All that matters is the fact that the determinant of the square  matrix is not equal to zero, so whether you want to make $<-1,-28> $ or any other vector, you can always do that (uniquely!!!) with your given vectors $a$ and $b$.
I do not know where you exactly stand in linear algebra, but there are other linear algebra approaches as well to do your problem...Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract twice the second equation from the first

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t - -10t &=& -1 - -56\\
11t &=& 55\\
t &=& 5\\
2s + t &=& -1\\
s &=& -3\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Now check that this s and t work.